# Laravel vue js deploy application on live

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I have created a project on laravel using vue js. Where my frontend is totally based on vue js and i am using laravel apis for backend. My project structure is like :

```
--app
--bootstrap
--config
--database
--fontend //This is my vue js code
  -- assets
  -- layout
  -- mode_modules
  -- pages
-- public
-- resources
```

... and so on.

I have run this command on my frontend folder

npm run build

It created a folder dist in frontend, now what will be the next step ?

My Server Information Ubuntu (Apache)

Answer (score 1):

You should just copy contents of dist folder on your server main folder, or of you have folder structure with folders like public/www/web, then there.

If you want to run "live" on wamp or xamp then copy to folder www.

Of course if you already have working backend

Answer (score 0):

You just copy contents inside the dist folder from your xampp/wampp folder.
and on Ubuntu server place inside directory `/var/www/html` folder.

or if you want to place inside any folder on the server like `/var/www/html/front`
then on front folder place contents inside front folder  then point domain to that front fodler.